# ezPublish error: index: Undefined module: eventcalendar

Tags: php, ezpublish

We have received below error in the error log file and also not able to view events on the event page. Also not able to find relevant script.

```
index: Undefined module: eventcalendar
error/view.php:
Error ocurred using URI: /dffestival_eng_GB/eventcalendar/fullcalendarprogramme
```

We are using eZ Publish Community Project 2012.6 version.

Could anyone please explain how to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: Have you made any progress on that issue ? If yes, please consider marking it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eZ Publish Community Project 2012.6 is an eZ Publish 5 version of eZ Publish and the module you referred to is probably a custom one, based on the legacy project.

This means that its source code should be in ezpublish_legacy/extension/.

eZ Publish 5 requires legacy modules to be well defined in their `module.ini.append.php`.

First, find the extension where your custom module is. You probably have a module view called `fullcalendarprogramme.php` defined in a directory like this `ezpublish_legacy/extension/<EXTENSIONNAME>/modules/eventcalendar/`

Then edit the related `module.ini` file in `ezpublish_legacy/extension/<EXTENSIONNAME>/settings/module.ini.append.php` and make sure it looks like this :

```php
<?php /* #?ini charset="utf-8"?
[ModuleSettings]
ExtensionRepositories[]=EXTENSIONNAME
ModuleList[]=eventcalendar
*/
```

Note that the `fullcalendarprogramme` view might be defined in another script. You'll find the mapping between the view's name and the script in the `module.php` file of the module :

```php
$ViewList['fullcalendarprogramme'] = array(
    'script' => 'fullcalendarprogramme.php'
);
```